# Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [47,1000], In[1]: [4096,256]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I'm new to TensorFlow and am following a tutorial. I'm trying to do image captioning using VGG. I am getting an error that says:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTvDx.png)

This is my code:

```py
model = define_model(vocab_size, max_length)  
epochs = 20

steps = len(train_descriptions)

for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
    model.save('model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
```

I'm just following the tutorial but that video was taken a long time ago. Since I'm new to this I don't understand this error. I tried `model.fit()` also. But, nothing works. Please, help me to rectify this.

https://github.com/nitinkaushik01/Deep_and_Machine_Learning_Projects/blob/master/Image_Caption_Project/Image_caption_Project.ipynb - This is the tutorial I'm following.

Comment: post the full code so that people can find the error

Comment: https://github.com/nitinkaushik01/Deep_and_Machine_Learning_Projects/blob/master/Image_Caption_Project/Image_caption_Project.ipynb 



Here's the code from the tutorial which I'm following

Comment: @DankDizaster Could plz give me the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. solved after apply the below modification  inputs1 --> 1000 instead
   of 4096     se1 --> 47 instead of 256   decoder2 --> 47 instead of 256
   fe2 --> 47 instead of 256   se3 --> 47 instead of 256
2. or just update inputs1  to 1000 i think it will solve the issue

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I'm not clear what to do in the code. If possible can you tell me where exactly I should change? Since I'm new to this, I don't know what to do exactly

Comment: in the previous part of the code , change the input layer to be 1000 instead of 4096

Comment: Thanks, it worked. May I know why by changing it to 1000 works?

Comment: to match the input layer input shape